# Regex replacing couples of symbols by HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to replace all the couples of symbols "$$" with some HTML tag, say, `<someTag></someTag>`.

I use this regular expression but it doesn't cover all the cases:

```
\$\$(\S[^\*]+\S)\$\$
```

```
'aaa $$123$$ c$ ddd'.replace(/\$\$(\S[^\*]+\S)\$\$/g, '<a1>$1</a1>') // works

'aaa $$123$$ c$ $$ddd$$'.replace(/\$\$(\S[^\*]+\S)\$\$/g, '<a1>$1</a1>') // doesn't work, should be 'aaa <a1>123</a1> c$ <a1>ddd</a1>'
```

```js
console.log('aaa $$123$$ c$ ddd'.replace(/\$\$(\S[^\*]+\S)\$\$/g, '<a1>$1</a1>')) // works

console.log('aaa $$123$$ c$ $$ddd$$'.replace(/\$\$(\S[^\*]+\S)\$\$/g, '<a1>$1</a1>')) // doesn't work, should be 'aaa <a1>123</a1> c$ <a1>ddd</a1>'
```

Comment: Maybe you want `\$\$([^\s$*]*)\$\$`?

Comment: @zer00ne I want to find every couple of ```$$``` and replace them to the opening and closing tag.

Comment: @mimic IC, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76275619/2813224).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to use the non greedy dot-all approach:  `/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/sg`
https://regex101.com/r/upveAX/1
Using the Dot alone will always be faster since it doesn't rely on assertion or class structures,
which add 3 times more overhead in performance.

```js
console.log('aaa $$123$$ c$ ddd'.replace(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/sg, '<a1>$1</a1>'));

console.log('aaa $$123$$ c$ $$ddd$$'.replace(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/sg, '<a1>$1</a1>'));
```

Should you choose to not use the Dot approach, you run the risk of orphaned
`$$` in your text as the regex mainly expect pairs of $$..$$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a regex solution, but this works. Explanation: Split the string using your delimiter (`$$`). Then create a new string `result` and insert each part of the array. Then check if the current index is odd or even and depending on that add either the opening tag (`prefix`) or the closing tag (`suffix`). I hope this helps!

```js
function replaceTag(string, delimiter, prefix, suffix){
  
  let parts = string.split(delimiter);
  let result = '';
  
  for(let index = 0; index < parts.length; index++){
  
    result += parts[index];
  
    if(index % 2 == 0 && index < parts.length - 1){
    
      result += prefix;
    
    }
    else if(index < parts.length - 1){
    
      result += suffix;
    
    }
  
  }
  
  return result;

}

console.log(replaceTag('aaa $$123$$ c$ ddd', '$$', '<my-tag>', '</my-tag>'));
console.log(replaceTag('aaa $$123$$ c$ $$ddd$$', '$$', '<my-tag>', '</my-tag>'));
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution! Do you think it's more reliable/fast/whatever than solution that uses regular expressions?

Comment: @mimic Regex can be computationally expensive, so for large strings this approach may be more performant. However, it's difficult to know for sure without testing the speeds for each method. What I like about this approach is that it is easy to read and adapt.

Comment: @mimic I just tried to benchmark it and it seems to be slower than using regex, however it is true that the approach is nice to read, however if you are a bit familiar with regex it might be even cleaner

Comment: @Apollo79 In that case, I'd probably go with a regex then if performance is a concern. I just like to avoid them because they can be tricky to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your regex matches `greedily`, meaning it matches the biggest part of the string it is able to match. To make it `ungreedy`, you have to add the `?` "lazy quantifier". I suggest using a regex like this one:

```
const regex = /\$\$(\w+?)\$\$/g
```

It matches two `$` signs and then at least one word character.

Answer (score 1):

The pure regex solution you can use is this regex,

```
\$\$((?:(?!\$\$).)+)\$\$
```

Where `((?:(?!\$\$).)+)` part ([aka tampered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)) will match anything except `$$` and the content you are looking for gets captured in group1 and then you can easily place it in the tags like you want.

This regex will even allow you to capture a single `$` if it is present in the content and will work even if your content is spread across multiple lines for which you can either replace `.` with `[\w\W]` or you can change `.` to something else as per your char matching needs,

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5KC7sb/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `/\$\$(\S+)\$\$/g`.

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` \$\$ ``` | Match literal "$$"... |
| ``` (\S+) ``` | ...capture one or more non-whitespace characters... |
| ``` \$\$ ``` | ...then match literal "$$". |

This ensures that a successful match requires any number of characters adjacent to two sets of "$$" with no spaces.

```js
const str = 'aaa $$123$$ $$c$ $$x $$ $$ddd$$';
const rgx = /\$\$(\S+)\$\$/g;
const sub = '<a1>$1</a1>';

const res = str.replace(rgx, sub);

console.log(res);
```